# How can I change the title of my Eclipse RCP at runtime?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'd like to change at runtime the name of my eclipse RCP application, so to include the name of the project the user is working on.

This seems a pretty simple question, but I was only able to find a way to set the name statically (in the article "branding your application").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` get hold of the `IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer` and set the title there. e.g:

```
public void preWindowOpen() 
{
    IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();        
    configurer.setTitle("Custom Name..."); 
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the user can open projects while the application is running (and not only at the beginning)... can I cache the windowConfigurer so to update the title after the window has been opened?

Comment: I answer to my own comment: yes, I can cache it and the title is correctly updated when I call method setTitle()

Answer (score 5):

There is a simpler way to do it, after I tried to do it as suggested here, I got into problems getting a hold of the `Application` or `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor`. The solution was simply to get the shell of the workbench window and `setText`:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell().setText("My new title");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can update the title at any time by burrowing down through the Application object:

```
Application.getApplication().getWorkbenchAdvisor().getWorkbenchWindowAdvisor().setTitle();
```

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing. I hold the getWindowConfigurer(); in some static reference.

```
Utility.configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
```

Then use this reference anywhere to update application title.

```
Utility.configurer.setTitle("My New Title");
```

Comment: it seems to me that this only works with a single window...in my case I just set a non-static class field and I can do that even if several windows are open!